# How to create file with no headers

Tags: c#, file

I need to create 100 files and every file to contain only a number between 1 and 100.
I am usinig this code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
     TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(i.ToString(), true);

     tw.WriteLine(i.ToString());
     tw.Close(); 

}
```

It's work but the files are bigger than expected (3 bytes). I created a file (manually) that contain the number 1(digit) and compare it(hash) with the other one...  they are not the same!
But they contain equal string, in this case "1".

Comment: It's probably the encoding you're using. When you did so *manually*, which encoding was used?

Comment: @Yuck ANSI, I guess. But in this case it's still a problem. Is it possible to create a file with no encoding, no headers, nothing, so if i hash it and hash a string(that's in the file) to get the same results?

Comment: When you say header, you are referring to the BOM, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I bet that WriteLine is adding a carriage return which is cr/lf. That would be two extra bytes. If you use Write does the problem go away?

Comment: No need to bet, this is exactly the reason.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect with write!

Answer (score 1):

Use the File.WriteAllText method, it's easier in this case and does a better job of cleaning up after itself that you're doing. Also, explicitly use ASCII encoding - otherwise you'll likely end up with a UTF BOM prefix - which it seems you do not want.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    string istr = i.ToString();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(istr, istr + ".txt", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
}
```

Comment: For brevity's sake you can assume appropriate `using` statements if so desired...

Answer (score 0):

You should try [BinaryWeiter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx).

```
for (int i  = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(ms);
      w.Write(i.ToString());
   }
}
```

This will write length prefixed string into the stream. You can use FileStream if you want to save it to the disk.